# qalter to remove an advanced reservation

Tags: sungridengine

I would like to create an array job where the tasks don't all execute at the same time. The tasks will be enabled by some future command. The reason that I need this feature is that I want to aggregate what would otherwise be many related jobs but the data needed for all the jobs isn't available at the same time.

I thought that I could use qalter but it doesn't allow changing options by task. It seems that I can't even adjust the number of tasks in a job. The only remaining option that I have is to let all the tasks issue and sleep until the data is available but I don't like that solution as it results in wasted slots.

How can I get the behavior that I want, whereby an array job is created for a set of related tasks but the tasks issue in a controllable way?

Answer (score 0):

Use qalter command with -hard option and queue name..